# Get full text from TfidfVectorizer

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I am plotting a set of text documents in 2D and I noticed some outliers, I would like to be able to find out what these outliers are. I am using raw text and then using the TfidfVectorizer built into SKLearn.

```
  vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.5, max_features=None,
                                 min_df=2, stop_words='english',
                                 use_idf=True, lowercase=True)

  corpus = make_corpus(root)
  X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
```

To reduce to 2D I am using TruncatedSVD.

```
reduced_data = TruncatedSVD(n_components=2).fit_transform(X)
```

If I wanted to find what text document had the highest 2nd principle component (y axis) how would I do this?

Comment: Can you please share some of the text you're using just so we can replicate?

Comment: Its a very large data set. If you can replicate any data it should work. I just need it to follow the process above. Then find document with highest 2nd principle component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, from what I understand, you want to know which document maximizes a specific principal component. Here's the toy example I came up with:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD
import numpy as np

corpus = [
    'this is my first corpus',
    'this is my second corpus which is longer than the first',
    'here is yet another one, but it is brief',
    'and watch out for number four chuggin along',
    'blah blah blah my final sentence yada yada yada'
]

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english',
                             use_idf=True, lowercase=True)

# first get TFIDF matrix
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)

# second compress to two dimensions
svd = TruncatedSVD(n_components=2).fit(X)
reduced = svd.transform(X)

# now, find the doc with the highest 2nd prin comp
corpus[np.argmax(reduced[:, 1])]
```

Which yields:

```
'and watch out for number four chuggin along'
```

Comment: Yes just what I am looking for! Thanks!